# Emails sent by WordPress on Azure having images stripped

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, email

I currently have a site that is hosted as an Azure web app with WordPress 4.8.2 running on top of it.

When WordPress site sends an e-mail, the images are being stripped from the body of the e-mail and sent as attachments but I'm not 100% sure why. I think it may be caused by not technically being sent from the domain, but from an Azure Web App utilizing the domain name, but I don't know.

Has anyone had luck sending an email from WordPress on Azure but having the images show up in the body and not as attachments? I know it's a long show but I figured I would ask.

Comment: Are you using `wp_mail`? If you are, I've seen this happen if you aren't setting the content type to `html` in the `$headers` argument.

Comment: I'm using the `wp-mail-smtp` plugin, and it looks to be set `$headers[] = "Content-Type: text/html;";`

Comment: Does it happen when you have WP installed on your local machine? If it does, Azure has nothing to do with it.